# How to move an element over a SVG area without letting it out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an element [by now it's a div, but I can replace it for another thing if it's more suitable] I want to move over a SVG polygon, and I want it to no cross the SVG boundaries. The problem is that the user can click another place and the div will fly over areas that my SVG do not cover. I tried to use getBoundingClientRect(), but it sees the SVG as a bounding box and do not recognise the polygon area.

Is there anyway it can be done?

**EDIT:** This is the function I'm using to get the click position [with some workaround that I plan to fix later] and change the assets of the moving div:

```
$('.svg-area').click(function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = (e.pageX - offset.left) + 120;
    var y = (e.pageY - offset.top) + 160;
    $('.diego').html('<img src="assets/img/diego_diagonal_frente.gif">');
    $('.diego').animate({
        'top': y,
        'left': x
    }, 1500, function(){
        $('.diego').html('<img src="assets/img/diego_diagonal_parado.gif">');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of the code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Call getBoundingClientRect() on the polygon rather than the svg.

Comment: The polygon **is** the SVG.